# Upgrading Laravel 4.2 to 5 Sentry not working

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to upgrade from 4.2 to 5 (and then actually upgraded to 5.1) but I'm having major problems with sentry

I followed instructions to add sentry to L5 here:
[How can I use sentry with laravel 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28538577/how-can-i-use-sentry-with-laravel-5)

With no luck.

Where I'm basically stuck is I got this on my controller:

```
$user = User::find(Sentry::getUser()->id);
```

When I try to view the page I get:

Trying to get property of non-object

So it seems it's simply not working.
I've tried multiple ways to get it to work, another one being:
https://cartalyst.com/manual/sentry/2.1#migrations
migration:

```
php artisan migrate --package=cartalyst/sentry
```

doesn't work with it though, as I understand this was removed. I really don't know could that help me with any way? Not very knowledgeable with this :)

Original app is not coded by me so I have not integrated the sentry in first place so I might be missing something obvious.