# how to install sentry package for laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, package, composer-php, sentry

I've tried installing **Laravel Sentry** package for the last version of **Laravel 5.4**, but it seems original package doesn't support above Laravel 4 version
then I've tried other methods but didn't get a straight answer
so I want to know if anybody has it installed completely and how?

Comment: https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-laravel

Comment: Looks like this question was already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28687629/1580028

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use sentry with laravel 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28538577/how-can-i-use-sentry-with-laravel-5)